# Azure EventGrid validationURL

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I'm trying to do some testing with Azure EventGrid.  As such, I'm using https://requestloggerbin.herokuapp.com as an endpoint for a subscription.  According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events) the subscription can be manually validated by calling the validationURL with a GET request.

However, here is my validation request, and as can be seen, it does not contain any validationUrl

`[{
  "id": "d476af6b-787c-4a8d-8ec4-2362952e5fe4",
  "topic": "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/microsoft.eventgrid/topics/down",
  "subject": "",
  "data": {
    "validationCode": "XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX"
  },
  "eventType": "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent",
  "eventTime": "2018-05-09T12:41:35.3229136Z",
  "metadataVersion": "1",
  "dataVersion": "2"
}]`

How do I manually validate a subscription request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual handshake mechanism was introduced in the 2018-05-01-preview version of the Event Grid service. This introduces an additional validation URL in addition to the validation code. To create an event subscription using this new preview API version, you can use the Event Grid CLI extension (az extension add —name eventgrid), or use the latest C# or Python preview SDK of Event Grid to create the event subscription.

Comment: Are you saying that adding the subscription via the az CLI will generate the validationURL whereas adding it via the Azure GUI portal will not?

Comment: Yes, that is what you are saying :-)  The ValidationURL is returning {"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Invalid URL. Please try again with a valid verification URL."}}

Comment: @J.KalyanaSundaram also you can use a REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/eventsubscriptions/createorupdate with api-version=2018-05-01-preview, it's working well

Comment: Adding links missing from @j-kalyana-sundaram answer: [SubscriptionValidationEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication) and [C# client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid) nuget,

Comment: Announced at //Build - [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bn0N8SYqdU8&feature=youtu.be&list=PLlrxD0HtieHg7uB3_amVXvaRgxIcXLtYD&t=1156)